# How to store Observer on_completed result

Tags: python, python-3.x, rx-py

I am relatively new to Rx and RxPy - there is one fundamental thing that I am trying to do which is access a value that I store at the end of an Observer `on_completed`. I have a feeling I am either missing something very obvious, or I am perhaps bending the Observable concept into something that it's not meant to be. Either way, hoping I can get some guidance on this.

I've looked over the documentation at things like `materialize` but they don't quite seem to match up. Have also looked into `Do` and `Disposable` but can't find many examples that are close to what I need.

```py
import rx
from rx import operators as ops
from rx.core import Observer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class PipelineObserver(Observer):
        def __init__(self):
            self.status = None

        def on_next(self, payload):
            print(payload)

        def on_error(self, err):
            print(err)

        def on_completed(self):
            self.status = "Done"
            return self.status

     ## This returns a disposable, not the actual value I want. Which in this case is self.status
    output = rx.from_([1, 2]).subscribe(
        PipelineObserver()
    )

    print(output) ## Hoping for "Done" which is stored in self.status, not disposable class
```

Is there anyway to access a value a value from the on_completed method? Short of saving something as a global variable (which seems like a bad idea to me) I'm not sure it's possible? Basically whatever it output by `on_completed` or something similar. Maybe `Do` or `Finally`?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out, posting here in case anyone else runs into this. Due to this operation I am looking for being one that has to run after an observable is completed, it has to be a blocking operation. The `run()` function is used for this.

```py
import rx
from rx import operators as ops
from rx.core import Observer

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class PipelineObserver(Observer):
        def __init__(self):
            self.status = None

        def on_next(self, payload):
            print(payload)

        def on_error(self, err):
            print(err)

        def on_completed(self):
            self.status = "Done"

    # First, seperate out the observer and observable:
    my_list = rx.from_([1, 2])

    my_list.subscribe(
        PipelineObserver()
    )

    # Say I want to return an integer of the count of items, I can use this:
    output = my_list.pipe(
       ops.count()
    ).run()

    print(output)
    # Notice the run command at the end of the chain.
    # Output: 2
```

There might be other/better ways of doing this but this will work for now!